# parent.document gives undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have two level parent-child iframe hierarchy in my HTML pages. I want to get an object of parent window document in its child document for some manipulation. I works majorly with Google Chrome.

parent.document gives 'undefined' in Google Chrome, while in Mozilla it works fine. What's the catch?

For reference, please find below the content of the three files demonstrating the issue,

**First file: 'one.html'**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="one_1" name="one_1" />
    <iframe id="one" name="one" src="two.html">
</body>
</html>
```

**Second file: 'two.html'**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="two_1" name="two_1" />
    <iframe id="two" name="two" src="three.html">
</body>
</html>
```

**Third file: 'three.html'**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function callme() {
        alert(parent.document)
        alert(top.document)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="three_1" name="three_1" />
    <button id="click" name="click" onclick="return callme()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that 'one.html' is opened with Google Chrome, when I click on the 'Click Me' button, two successive alert boxes appears with 'undefined' value. When I open 'one.html' in Mozilla, it gives two 'objectHTMLDocument' valued alert boxes appears.

Please find below the console messages while clicking on 'Click Me' button,

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/two.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/three.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
                                                                 three.html:6
callme                                                           three.html:6
onclick                                                         three.html:13

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/one.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/three.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
                                                                 three.html:7
callme                                                           three.html:7
onclick                                                         three.html:13
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The catch is [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting).

Comment: @bfavaretto just checked with contentDocument, still no gain :(

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @bfavaretto Please find the code in question description

Comment: Just tested in Chrome (Chrome 25, OSX 10.7), and it worked for me.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I just checked the same code with Chrome (Version 26.0.1410.43 m, up-to-date) and it did not work out. I simply can't figure out the root cause. Could you help?

Comment: I don't know, I tested again, and it worked again. Did you use that exact code? To double check, I replaced the alert calls with console.log, and verified in the browser console that the returned documents were the correct ones. Did you check the console for errors? Also, I ran that using a local webserver. If you try to open one.html directly from the filesystem (with a file:// url), you'll get a security error. Maybe that's what's going wrong for you?

Comment: @bfavaretto: Please find the console logs in the question description now. There is no file system issue as such, I just checked out. Thanks.

Comment: You're using a `file:///` URL. As I said in the previous comment, that won't work. Use a all-in-one webserver like XAMPP or WAMP, or upload your test files to a live server, and it should work. Double-clicking HMTL files to open them in the browser causes several security issues like the ones you're having. You must setup a proper development environment on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would inject from top-down as opposed to accessing bottom-up.  I would set a variable in an iFrame by selecting it and storing it into a variable like so:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('one');
```

And then inject a reference to the parent:

```
frame.contentWindow.frame_parent_reference = window;
```

And then perform this in the next child iFrame replacing "one" with "two".  That way, by third.html, we don't ask for parent or top, but can do the following:

```
alert(frame_parent_reference.document);
alert(frame_parent_reference.frame_parent_reference.document);
```

Perhaps not super elegant but it definitely gives you a lot of control (and you can check if the custom reference exists for security).

Good luck!